# Manage multiple SRID on a single PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, srid

I'm developing a web-GIS based on PostGIS. When I create a GIS-enalbled table on PostGIS I've to specify the SRID of the data, for example an UTM Zone (eg. UTM 33N SRID 32633).
Is there a way to keep the project scalable and put in the same table data of different SRID (eg. 32633 and 32632 to cover all Italy) without use a global geographic SRID (like WGS84 and similars)?

Thank you

Comment: All is possible, it depends what do you want to do with the data. I.e. you can put all data in a table and than define views for the different srid. Describe better you scenario and you will get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd end up in a world of pain if you try to combine different SRIDs in one column (how do you know how to display the layer properly?).

However, you could create a table with two geometry columns. To make things more maintainable you could e.g. have triggers that update the "other" column's geometry when one column changes...

```
create table table_with_2_geoms (
geom_32633 geometry(geometry,32633),
geom_32632 geometry(geometry,32632)
);
```